# The package is not available in a stable-enough version

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Following situation:

- app requires `andig/dbcopy` in dev version: 
  `composer require andig/dbcopy:dev-master`
- `andig/dbcopy` requires `symfony/console`in dev version (due to a bug in 2.5):

  ```
  "require": {
      "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*",
      "symfony/console": "2.6.*@dev"
  },
  ```

Now, when adding `andig/dbcopy` to the app using `composer require`, composer complains about stability:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for andig/dbcopy dev-master -> satisfiable by andig/dbcopy[dev-master].
    - andig/dbcopy dev-master requires symfony/console 2.6.*@dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

No `minimum-stability` settings have been defined, the app already has a dependency on a `dev-master` package.

I've read https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion but I'm still confused as to why composer fails to install even though

- all stability settings are explicitly defined and
- the app itself already has another dependency on "dev-master" which works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put:

```
"symfony/console": "2.6.*@dev"
```

in your main composer.json. You must override stability requirement directly.

Comment: Excellent. Much better than adding minimum-stability on the app!